# Unable to Use Google Play or Log Into Google On My Note 2.

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-services, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I installed the CyanogenMod 13 Marshmallow for my Note 2. I haven't been able to log into Google Play. I can log into my GMail but everything else doesn't work. I also keep getting "Unfortunately google play services has stopped".

I changed the host file but is there a new IP i need to change to or?

Answer (score 0):

What I did that really solved it for me was:

I first of all used [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp). Before hand I was using [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) which wasn't working too well. (IDK why).

<sup>I have a Galaxy Note 2 and installed the CWM 13 Marshmallow ROM and installed the BANKS Open GAPPS along with it.</sup>

<sup>I could not log into Google. The Gmail would work but I couldn't log into anything Google especially Google Play. I download and uninstalled google play services like a thousand times.</sup>

TO FINALLY SOLVE MY ISSUE, I rooted my device (if it isn't already, you need to root) also everytime you do a factory reset you need to re-root.

I went into RECOVERY MODE on TWRP and went to INSTALL. I chose the CM13 ROM & the BANKS OPEN GAPPS that I had already on the device. I basically reinstalled it. You want to "SWIPE TO FLASH BOTH". Wipe you DALVIK/DATA. **IMPORTANT:** Do not boot between flashing the ROM and flashing GApps!

Your device should be rebooted after this. It should be working after this without you having to installed Services or anything.

Comment: Let me guess: Before that, you've booted into the "normal system" between flashing CM and flashing GApps? I don't know what's behind that, but most howtos say "don't do that" ;)

Comment: i have no idea because it was my first time ever installing custom rom, but yeah it was frustrating but I'm glad I figured it out

Comment: I take this as a "yes", and updated your answer accordingly. A note, though: You don't need to root again if you do a factory-reset – unless it was a "systemless root". All the "rooting files" are usually installed on `/system`, which is not affected by factory-resets. You might wish to update that in your answer as well ;)